# Check SIM status by USSD query from site

Tags: gsm, ussd

I want to check anyone phonenumber's online status by query from serverside without any notice to user. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

An operator can see the latest location updates etc from a mobile device, but I am guessing this is not your use case.

To do it as a third party service, you would need to either implement an instant messaging like availability service or leverage or extend an existing open source one like Tox (https://tox.chat), Telegram (https://telegram.org), Linphone (http://www.linphone.org) etc.